# A Better Segmentation Method

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I'm working on a project for classifying different flower species. I extracted color and texture features and I used neural networks. There were also a preprocessing step before these steps. I used Otsu's method to remove background, but I think it didn't work well and I need a better method. Do you suggest a better method or methods for removing background pixels from image? Also I'm converting background pixels to black after segmentation and It might affect color moments. How can I eliminate this problem? Thanks. Here is my code for segmentation( I used skimage):

```
# Otsu Segmentation

# Read image
image = img_as_ubyte(imread('../../Samples/sunflower19.jpeg'))

# Convert image to gray and calculate histogram
grey  = img_as_ubyte(rgb2gray(image))
hist = np.histogram(image, bins=np.arange(0, 256))

# Calculate threshold and remove background
threshold = threshold_otsu(grey)
image_br = deepcopy(image)
image_br[grey < threshold] = 0
```

Some sample images:

[image: A bad one]
[image: It's quite good]
[image: Very bed segmentation]
[image: It's bad too]

Comment: Could you provide some sample images?

Comment: Yes. I'm adding.

Comment: Pure black (0,0,0) won’t affect spatial moments, but will affect the mean, standard deviation, etc. of the color. To avoid that compute statistics only over the foreground pixels.

Comment: Yes it's another problem. They affect mean, std and other properties of color. I calculated them using Numpy and Scipy libraries. I'm just making a call to library functions and provide image. Is there a way to provide only foreground pixels to these functions? It changes from image to image.

Comment: I found out a method for excluding black pixels from calculation of color moments. It excludes black pixels from array and return new one: np.setdiff1d(self.image[:,:,0], [0]).

Comment: `image_br[grey >= threshold]` is all pixels with a value above the threshold. Pass that result onto the statistics functions.

Comment: After masking, zero values don't affect the sum but don't they affect the number of values? If so sample mean calculated smaller than exact value.

Comment: If the flower is always centered in the image and it covers a significant portion of it, say 40%-50%, you can define an ROI and extract it. This will most probably minimize the background. And, is there any specific reason for engineering your own features than letting the neural network learn the features?

Comment: Actually my project advisor wants using texture recognition along neural networks. Flowers are mostly centered in database images. How can I define a ROI?